# Using SVG image files to train a model

Tags: python, image, svg, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use SVG image files to train a model in Python. When I run the below code in Jupyter notebook, I am getting below error. Also `Image.open()` does not work here. Is there a way to get this code working for `.svg` image files?

```
from PIL import Image
drawing = svg2rlg("/content/America_Online_logo.svg")
base_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/America_Online_logo.svg"
base_image_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(fname = "America_Online_logo.svg", origin = 
base_url,)
Image.open(base_image_path)
a = plt.imread(base_image_path)
from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2 
width, height = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(base_image_path).size
```

Getting following error:

```
UnidentifiedImageError Traceback (most recent call last)
`<ipython-input-39-a31080608fad> in <module>()`

    from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2
    width, height = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(base_image_path).size
    img_nrows = 400
    img_ncols = int(width * img_nrows / height)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
    warnings.warn(message)
    raise UnidentifiedImageError( "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else 
    fp))
```

Comment: What does python3 -m PIL say are the supported image formats?

Comment: Note also that in [the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/plugins.html#) there is no SVG plugin listed so what is it that leads you to believe SVG is supported by PIL?

Comment: You may be able to use a third-party utility like [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) to convert SVG files into an image file format that PIL supports.